# merging multiple external git repos into one git repo and still being able to track the origins

Tags: git

I am porting/gardening/maintaining a very fast moving 3rd party project, which is composed of many git repos. They are using repo as they manager and their system works pretty good. Mine however, not so much. During the porting I end up modifying multiple repos at a time and try to group these changesets together by naming convention. But it is too time consuming. And now there is a new requirement from my organization as well. People are not happy with pulling gazillion git repos, which takes a long time. So they want me to combine everything into one git repo and remove unused parts of the repos (there are quite a bit of testing code and their golden outputs).

Now the question: is this doable in git? Can this

```
  A-B-C
       \
        L1

  D-E-F
       \
        L1'-L2
```

Be turned into:

```
   A-D-E-B-C-F-L1-L2
```

while it is still possible to pull and rebase from the external repos?

I know this is aggresive and probably not the best idea; but I am trying to avoid maintaining yet another git repo, which will pretty much be a shallow copy of all the patched sources and will not have a history.

Comment: I'm affraid your question is too opinion-based. Some people may like `repo`, some, as you've already noticed, don't. The same thing is for [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) and [git merge with subtree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). I would suppose that subtree-merge could work for your case but only if you don't need to push some changes back to the upstream (it's still possible to automate, but with some pain)

Comment: another possible solution would be to create local automatic mirrors of all repositories, so synchronizing of a developer repo(s) would be performed faster, within your LAN.

Comment: Well, I was not really asking for an opinion. I am wondering if this is technically possible by some git magic. I can do parts of it by filter-branch. But I could not figure out how to keep up-to-date with the tip of tree.

Comment: Currently I am using your second suggestion. I have local repos that I pull from the head. Then I rebase my changesets on them and then make them available to my internal customers through repo. However, like I have mentioned, when a changeset affects multiple repos at the same time, my life becomes pretty difficult. And people are not happy about waiting half an hour for files they dont really need. Hence, the question.

Comment: git subtree-merge looks interesting. I will read about it. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely I should mention the [git subtree](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/subtree) solution. In my distribution it is available right among other git subcommands, you may need to fetch it from contribs. It differs from `git subtree merge` and likely provides a more "seamless" experience for end-users and repository administrators.

Comment: I think subtree is as close as I can get to what I want. Does not look like I can rebase when using it. It seems to merge every time I pull from the external sources. And I cant get logs on individual files either. So I have decided not to use it. But it was the right direction. Thanks